# Inner Join condition

Tags: sql, database, inner-join

I have two tables "cats_lables" and "classified_cats", where in "cats_lables" table I can only add a new classes/lables of cats. And then I can use this class/lable to classify new cats and add them to the table "classified cats".

so the tables are like this:

```
cats_lables: 

id   cats_lable
1     Polydactyl
2     Snowshoe
3     Calico


classified_cats:

id   class_id   cat_age    placeOfBorn   cat_price 
1          1     3 months   Eygipt         1000
2          3     6 months   Lebanon        2000
```

so, this is the query that shows only the cats that have been classified:

```
SELECT "cats_lables".*,
        CAST(COUNT("classified_cats"."class_id") AS int) AS class_count
      FROM "Labels"
      INNER JOIN "classified_cats"
        ON "classified_cats"."class_id"="cats_lables"."id"
      GROUP BY "cats_lables"."id"
      ORDER BY class_count DESC
```

But I want to upgrade my query to show also the cat class even if there is no cat assigned to it.

how can I fix my query?

Comment: LEFT JOIN.................

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: Thank you @MitchWheat, this is it .

Answer (score 0):

A left join should do it for you.

```
 SELECT "cats_lables",
        CAST(COUNT("classified_cats"."class_id") AS int) AS class_count
   FROM "Labels"
  LEFT JOIN "classified_cats"
     ON "classified_cats"."class_id"="cats_lables"."id"
  GROUP BY "cats_lables"."id"
  ORDER BY class_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing the query like this:

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(cc."class_id") AS class_count
FROM "Labels" l LEFT JOIN
     "classified_cats" cc
     ON cc."class_id" = l."id"
GROUP BY l."id"
ORDER BY class_count DESC;
```

Notes:

- `"cats_labels"` is not in the `FROM` clause.  I am assuming you mean `"Labels".
- I strongly encourage you to *never* use double quotes on identifiers.  They just make queries harder to write and to read.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You don't specify your database, but not all databases support aggregating by a primary key and then selecting other columns from the table -- although that is permitted in the standard.